# Minor Losses Pipeflow Momentum vs Steady Flow

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pipelines

First post in the engineering forum

**The Problem Statement** 
I have designed a prototype agitator tank - its a circular square duct like pipe filled with incompressible liquid (acetone/water) which spins on a vertical axis.

[image]

I had intended to build fluid momentum thru viscous action (achieving something akin to solid body rotation) then rapidly stop the pipe body hoping the fluid momentum will continue to circulate a flow for a time until viscosity degrades it

I have calculated all the minor and major losses in the 'circuit' and they indicate that viscosity should degrade quite slowly but experimenting it appears that the fluid stops flowing almost immediately.

**My Question**

Have I miscalculated the losses as the K-values I have used as they appear derived from steady flow.

$h_{Minor loss}= K.\frac{v^2}{2g}\ $

Is there a difference in how the relative velocity $v^2$ to the pipe is developed

*NB: Interestingly it does not require any more force to stop the full tank than the empty one so I'm really confused as to where this fluid momentum is going.
Additionally no matter how well I fill it (displacing all air , putting under pressure) I can still hear 'sloshing' when I stop the body, is there some sort of cavitation going on ?*

Comment: Welcome to Engineering Stack Exchange!  This is a well done question.  However, while Mathematics and Physicists don't deal to much with the actual dimensions until near the very end, in engineering it's always where we begin.  Can you tell us the velocity, viscosity, and dimensions of your tank?  If you're able to measure the torque to start and stop spinning, can you tell us what you've measured?  And, most of all, what's the value for K you're using?.Exact measurements are more important here then they are on Physics and Mathematics.